# VBA Code Excel: I want the macro to delete rows by using multiple ifs

Tags: excel, vba

I want the macro to delete all 3 rows if the preceding cell is blank, the cell itself has the value "Security" and the next cell is also blank. Is it possible? Help appreciated! :) The data rows has many such numbers:

```
C23= Blank
C24= Security
C25= Blank
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you have basic method you wrote? (in vba)

Comment: *I want* You want us to write code for you?

Comment: Welcome to SO, but we want you to have a look at how [ask] a question with a [mcve]. Tell us where you are getting stuck/getting an error in your code. This isn't a free coding service.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below.
A1 
A2 Security
A3 
A4 Security
A5 Security

```
Dim cell As Range

For Each cell In Range("A1:A5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

If cell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = "" Then
    If cell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "" Then
        Range(cell.Offset(-1, 0).Address, cell.Offset(1, 0).Address).Clear
    End If
End If
Next
```

If you want to delete the entire row and shift xlup then you can use entirerow.delete shift:=xlup option.

Thanks